# Russian characters are turned junk when using Filezilla to FTP

Tags: encoding, ftp, filezilla

When I tried to FTP Russian named files, it is showing as "junk" characters in Linux machine. But when I copied the Russian names it is correctly showing up.

Is there any settings or anything need to be done in Filezilla during FTP. I tried with both Ascii and Binary mode.

The Linux machine is having locale set to ru_RU.cp1251.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FTP was invented with US-ASCII as character set in mind, so it lacks a concept for different character sets at all. The server sends filenames as-is and the client has to properly interpret them.

FileZilla can do that as well: Add your site to the Site Manager (`File` then `Site Manager…`). For your site, go to `Charset` tab and select `Use custom charset`. As I do not know how the accepted character set name is, you have to try a bit: `cp-1251`, `windows-1251`, `cp1251`, etc.

If possible, make sure the FTP server supports UTF-8 and then always use UTF-8 (Unicode). This way you do not have such problems anymore.

ASCII and binary modes by the way are completely unrelated to character sets - see [FileZilla Wiki regarding data type](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Data_Type) for more information.

Comment: I was searching around for something like this.  I used `cp-1251` and although I still couldn't read the folder names, I was able to download them which was better than getting the errors I was getting.

Comment: Great! You just saved my butt! I'll be able to get my homework done! :D